# Prestashop combinations issue

Tags: prestashop-1.7, php-7.0

I'm creating new products with some combinations. When trying to set up 4 combinations, only 2 of them are showing on front.

[image]

As you can see at picture, I've got 2 rows for combinations (Colored Ash and Natural Veneer). One of them are showing correctly and not the other. Inspecting the code I can take a look to list elements. First it's correct but second one nope.

On backend, combinations are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the setting of your shop, in Paramètre de la boutique => Products => Block product sheet, you have not put:
"Show unavailable attributes on the product card" to no?

Regards

Comment: Still not working. Could it be a problem of max_vars on server config?